# Does Contact Editor Extension work with Version 5.2.1?

Tags: extension

I just upgraded to version 5.2.1 from 4.7.27.  I tried using the contact editor extension to change a contact type but I get a "Page Not Found" error.  As part of the upgrade, I switched to PHP version 7.1.  I use CiviCRM with WordPress.

Does the Contact Editor extension work with 5.2.1?

Comment: Did you clear the caches of CiviCRM? And cleared the templates_c directory?

Answer (score 3):

I just identified the issue & fixed it & tagged another release of Contact Editor

Answer (score 2):

Yes contact editor works on 5.2.1 - I don't think 7.1 is an issue. My guess is the issue is caching. Sometimes immediately post-upgrade there is a caching issue. You can use the api (e.g drush cvapi System.flush) or there is a place in the UI - not sure if they flush exactly the same things - or hit the url civicrm/menu/rebuild on your site

Comment: I cleared the templates_c directory when updating.  I just use the "Settings - Cleanup Caches and Update Paths" function.  I still get the same error after I cleared the Caches.

Comment: I think there is a permission you need to assign?

It shows in the middle menu